# Quick way to write class name in ul with emmet?

Tags: html, emmet

I want to write the following ul list.

```
<ul>
    <li class="home">home</li>
    <li class="intro">intro</li>
    <li class="other">other</li>
    <li class="contact">contact</li>
</ul>
```

1.To write four lines.

```
home
intro
other
contact
```

2.To press v into visual mode ,and select all the four lines.
3.To <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>
4.To input  ul>li[class=""]*

```
<ul>
    <li class="">home</li>
    <li class="">intro</li>
    <li class="">other</li>
    <li class="">contact</li>
</ul>
```

At last to input home intro other contact into class="" one by one.
Is there more quick way write class name in ul with emmet?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
ul>li.home+li.intro+li.other+li.contact
```

Since you have custom class names which doesn't have a numerical pattern, you have to enter the class names manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be **quicker**, you can use the implicit tag names from Emmet.

```
ul>.home+.intro+.other+.contact
```

Available in cheat sheet https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/